# Hibernate Error detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, hibernate

SO I am trying to understand the relations between beans and connect my program to a DB using Hibernate.

I get this error, I read some other questions and answers about it but still don't understand how to solve it and why it happens.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.thp.spring.simplecontext.entity.Bateau
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758)
at com.thp.spring.simplecontext.dao.impl.BateauDAOImpl.create(BateauDAOImpl.java:31)
at com.thp.spring.simplecontext.main.AppJavaConfigMain.main(AppJavaConfigMain.java:14)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.thp.spring.simplecontext.entity.Bateau
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:773)
... 3 more
```

I see the root cause but still not inding the solution.

Here are the files of my code.
My two entities Moussaillon and Bateau:

```
package com.thp.spring.simplecontext.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "moussaillon")
public class Moussaillon {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "config")
private String config;

/*
 * Many to one ralation This means that moussaillon entity will have a foreign
 * key column named "bateau_id" referring to primary attribute id of entity
 * bateau
 */
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "bateau_id")
private Bateau bateau;

public Moussaillon() {
}

public Moussaillon(String firstName, String lastName, String config, Bateau bateau) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.config = config;
    this.bateau = bateau;
}

//getters and setters are automatically created here

}
```

Second entity here:

```
package com.thp.spring.simplecontext.entity;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
 import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "bateau")
public class Bateau {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;
@Column(name = "name")
private String nom;
@Column(name = "type")
private String type;
@Column(name = "size")
private double taille;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="bateau")
private List<Moussaillon> moussaillons;

public Bateau() {

}

public Bateau(int id, String nom, String type, double taille) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.nom = nom;
    this.type = type;
    this.taille = taille;
}

//getters and setters are automatically created here
}
```

I have two DAO interfaces implemented in the corresponding DAOIMpl classes.

```
package com.thp.spring.simplecontext.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.thp.spring.simplecontext.dao.BateauDAO;
import com.thp.spring.simplecontext.entity.Bateau;
import com.thp.spring.simplecontext.entity.Moussaillon;


@Repository
public class BateauDAOImpl implements BateauDAO{

EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence");
EntityManager em=emf.createEntityManager();

@Override
public int create(int id, String name, String type, double taille) {

    return 0;
}

@Override
public int create(Bateau bateau) {
    em.persist(bateau);
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Bateau update(Bateau bateau, String name, String type, double taille) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void delete(Bateau bateau) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public Bateau findById(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Bateau findByMoussaillon(Moussaillon moussaillon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<Bateau> findAll() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

My second DAOImpl class:

```
package com.thp.spring.simplecontext.dao.impl;

//al

@Repository
public class MoussaillonDAOImpl implements MoussaillonDAO {

EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence");
EntityManager em=emf.createEntityManager();


@Override
public int create(Moussaillon moussaillon) {
    System.out.println("Starting Transaction");
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(moussaillon);

    return 0;
}

@Override
public Moussaillon update(Moussaillon moussaillon, String firstName, String lastName, String config) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void delete(Moussaillon moussaillon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public Moussaillon findById(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<Moussaillon> findAll() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<Moussaillon> findAllByBateau(int bateauId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

My main class

```
package com.thp.spring.simplecontext.main;

import com.thp.spring.simplecontext.dao.impl.BateauDAOImpl;
import com.thp.spring.simplecontext.dao.impl.MoussaillonDAOImpl;
import com.thp.spring.simplecontext.entity.Bateau;
import com.thp.spring.simplecontext.entity.Moussaillon;

public class AppJavaConfigMain {
    public static voidmain(String[] args){
    Bateau b1=new Bateau(3,"carthage","barque",10);
    BateauDAOImpl b=new BateauDAOImpl();
    b.create(b1);
    Moussaillon m1 = new Moussaillon();

    m1.setFirstName("gy");
    m1.setLastName("yg");
    m1.setConfig("java");
    m1.setBateau(b1);       //m1.setId(1);
    MoussaillonDAOImpl mdao = new MoussaillonDAOImpl();
    System.out.println("persist new moussaillon");
    mdao.create(m1);
    System.out.println("persist finished");


}
}
```

I use a DataBase named bateaumoussaillonJDBC.
In this DB I have two Tables:

```
CREATE DATABASE bateaumoussaillonJDBC;

CREATE TABLE bateaumoussaillonJDBC.bateau(
id int NOT NULL,
name CHAR(80) NOT NULL,
type CHAR(80) NOT NULL,
size DOUBLE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE bateaumoussaillonJDBC.moussaillon(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name CHAR(80) NOT NULL,
last_name CHAR(80) NOT NULL,
config CHAR(80) NOT NULL,
bateau_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
CONSTRAINT FK_BateauMoussaillon FOREIGN KEY (bateau_id)
REFERENCES bateaumoussaillonJDBC.bateau(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

You create constructor with `id` but it is auto increment in your entity class.
Change:

```
public Bateau(int id, String nom, String type, double taille) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.nom = nom;
    this.type = type;
    this.taille = taille;
}
```

To

```
public Bateau(String nom, String type, double taille) {
    this.nom = nom;
    this.type = type;
    this.taille = taille;
}
```

And in main:

```
 Bateau b1=new Bateau("carthage","barque",10); // without id number
```

Comment: In bateau there is no auto increment, just for moussaillon.
Even changing that and the database so that it would be coherent I get a new error message.
ERROR: Column 'bateau_id' cannot be null

Comment: "GenerationType.IDENTITY
The GenerationType.IDENTITY is the easiest to use but not the best one from a performance point of view. It relies on an auto-incremented database column and lets the database generate a new value with each insert operation. From a database point of view, this is very efficient because the auto-increment columns are highly optimized, and it doesn’t require any additional statements."